# Migrate QuotaBytesTotal/ QuotaBytesUsed from Google Drive Apis v2 to v3 in C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-drive-api

Under https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration I found that QuotaBytesTotal from the about section from GDrive v2 API was changed to storageQuota.limit.
QuotaBytesUsed was changed to storageQuota.usageInDrive. Can anyone give me an example on how I can call this in GApis.v3?

The old code I was using (Google Apis v2) was the following:

```
private long GetQuotaTotal(Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService service)
{
    var quotaBytesTotal = service.About.Get().Execute().QuotaBytesTotal;
    if (quotaBytesTotal == null)
        return 0;
    return (long) quotaBytesTotal;
}
```

For the QuotaBytesUsed exactly the same thing:

```
private long GetQuotaUsed(Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService service)
{
    var quotaBytesUsed = service.About.Get().Execute().QuotaBytesUsed;
    if (quotaBytesUsed == null)
        return 0;
    return (long) quotaBytesUsed;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
    public long GetDriveSpaceUsage()
    {
        try
        {
            AboutResource.GetRequest ag = new AboutResource.GetRequest(_CurrentDriveService);
            ag.Fields = "user,storageQuota";
            var response = ag.Execute();
            if (response.StorageQuota.Usage.HasValue)
            {
                return response.StorageQuota.Usage.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public long GetDriveSpaceLimit()
    {

        try
        {
            AboutResource.GetRequest ag = new AboutResource.GetRequest(_CurrentDriveService);
            ag.Fields = "user,storageQuota";
            var response = ag.Execute();
            if (response.StorageQuota.Limit.HasValue)
            {
                return response.StorageQuota.Limit.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return -1;
        }

    }
```

Comment: As additional, you might want to check the [Drive API Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/csharp/latest/). **`UsageInDrive`** and **`Usage`** can be found in the `StorageQuotaData` Class Reference. Hope this helps.